# Webpack on HTML change does not Live Reload

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, nodemon

I have the following Webpack configuration.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    publicPath: 'dist',
    writeToDisk: true,
    open: true,
    liveReload: true,
    hotOnly: true,
  },
  entry: './src/js/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
    publicPath: 'dist',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: function () {
                return [require('autoprefixer')];
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg)(\?\S*)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: '../fonts/',
              publicPath: '../fonts/',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '../css/app.css',
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
    }),
  ],
};
```

When I edit the HTML files it does not reload the browser like `nodemon`

These are my scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot --mode development"
  },
```

Comment: And by accident you didn't forget about HtmlWebpackPlugin? :)

Comment: @GrzegorzT. I am creating my .html file already in `dist` folder. I just want it to watch and reload it if anything is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `devServer.watchContentBase` to `true`, like this:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    watchContentBase: true
  }
};
```

> ## devServer.watchContentBase
>
> boolean
>
> Tell dev-server to watch the files served by the devServer.contentBase option. It is disabled by default. When enabled, file changes will trigger a full page reload.

(from https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwatchcontentbase)